# how to create a package

Tags: java

I just know how to create a package just by declaring it at the top of the class but I dont know the code for creating it

```
package myPackage;
class test{
system.out.println("Hello every one");


}
```

please provide me the code to compile it

Comment: It's really not clear what you're after. Do you just not know how to use the Java compiler at all, or are you thinking of something *specific* to packages?

Comment: i want to know the code to compile it and i want  a package myPackage to be created in which my test class to be reside

Comment: Please google for java tutorials and try out examples.  The above class will not compile as it is.

Comment: @Salman_Khan: What do you mean by "I want a package myPackage to be created" - what form do you expect this to take? The Java compiler will create a class file... but are you really after a jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be your lesson of the day :)

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Read from end to end, and don't forget this page http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html

Read these for compiling options:

- http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall97/cs461/jdkdocs/tooldocs/win32/javac.html
- http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html

Answer (score 1):

A package is 'created' by the folder hierarchy it is in. For example, your `test` class is in the `myPackage` package, which has to be in a folder called myPackage.

Answer (score 0):

If your classes are in packages, then Java expects your source files to be in a directory structure that looks like the package structure. In this case, make a directory called myPackage and put test.java in that directory. Then from the directory the myPackage directory is in, run `javac myPackage/test.java`. This will create a test.class file in the myPackage directory. If test.java had a main function defined in it, you could then, from the same directory, run `java myProject.test`.

Comment: is it necessary to create a package manually ,cant this compiler create a package for us since we are providing a code that is javac myPackage/test.java

Comment: @Salman_Khan no, compiler does not. Start using an IDE like Eclipse http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ they do most of the basic work for you

Answer (score 0):

The '*test*' class is supposed to be public, and put it under folder "*myPackage*". The folder is package.